# Why CooperatingNoDeadlock from 'Concurrency in practice' use double synchronized with same monitor?

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock, synchronized

In book java concurrency in practice you can find following code(10.6):

```
class CooperatingNoDeadlock {
    @ThreadSafe
    class Taxi {
        @GuardedBy("this") private Point location, destination;
        private final Dispatcher dispatcher;

        public Taxi(Dispatcher dispatcher) {
            this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
        }

        public synchronized Point getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public synchronized void setLocation(Point location) {
            boolean reachedDestination;
            synchronized (this) {
                this.location = location;
                reachedDestination = location.equals(destination);
            }
            if (reachedDestination)
                dispatcher.notifyAvailable(this);
        }

        public synchronized Point getDestination() {
            return destination;
        }

        public synchronized void setDestination(Point destination) {
            this.destination = destination;
        }
    }
```

---

```
   @ThreadSafe
    class Dispatcher {
        @GuardedBy("this") private final Set<Taxi> taxis;
        @GuardedBy("this") private final Set<Taxi> availableTaxis;

        public Dispatcher() {
            taxis = new HashSet<Taxi>();
            availableTaxis = new HashSet<Taxi>();
        }

        public synchronized void notifyAvailable(Taxi taxi) {
            availableTaxis.add(taxi);
        }

        public Image getImage() {
            Set<Taxi> copy;
            synchronized (this) {
                copy = new HashSet<Taxi>(taxis);
            }
            Image image = new Image();
            for (Taxi t : copy)
                image.drawMarker(t.getLocation());
            return image;
        }
    }

    class Image {
        public void drawMarker(Point p) {
        }
    }

}
```

lets research `setLocation` method:

```
public synchronized void setLocation(Point location) { //first synchronized
    boolean reachedDestination;
    synchronized (this) { // second synchronized
        this.location = location;
        reachedDestination = location.equals(destination);
    }
    if (reachedDestination)
        dispatcher.notifyAvailable(this);
    }
}
```

**I didn't understand something or double synchronization by same monitor useless?**

This code I found in the book and you can find it here:

[source](http://jcip.net/listings/CooperatingNoDeadlock.java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an error. Nested synchronization on the same monitor like that can serve no purpose.

The [errata](http://jcip.net/errata.html) cites this listing, "p.214: In Listing 10.6, `Taxi.setLocation` should not be a synchronized method. (The synchronized block in its body is correct, however.)"

Note that if the synchronization is placed on the block, the dispatcher can be notified that a taxi is available when it's not at its destination. This seems wrong, but perhaps there are other measures against this in this particular context.

Comment: But we have guarantee that destinationa achievement happens-before the dispatcher will see this notification. From my side it looks correct

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yes, but setting a new location that is *not* the destination can also *happen-before* the dispatcher receives a notification. So, for example, Thread A sets the taxi location to its destination, then Thread B resets the taxi destination and location, then Thread A continues, notifying the dispatcher that the taxi is available, even though it's on its way to a new destination.